# catalina.out logging same error continuously

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, bouncycastle

I am getting the following error when deploying to Tomcat

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Acceptor run

INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  
Could not load org.bouncycastle.crypto.modes.CBCBlockCipher.
The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes
as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access,
and has no functional impact.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
```

and then

```
SEVERE: Socket accept failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/crypto/modes/CBCBlockCipher
  at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher.engineSetMode(Unknown Source)
  at javax.crypto.Cipher$Transform.setModePadding(Cipher.java:357)
  at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:847)
  at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1348)
  at sun.security.ssl.CipherBox.(CipherBox.java:175)
  at sun.security.ssl.CipherBox.newCipherBox(CipherBox.java:208)
  ...
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Acceptor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:352)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

The NoClassDefFoundError exception is being logged into catalina.out continuously (looping) and catalina.out gets full in short time.

Tomcat version is 6.0.24.

Answer (score 0):

You should obviously remove the class causing the issues, since that is the expected behavior of tomcat if this Thread is frequently being invoked.